# how does semaphore behave if multiple threads try to lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand semaphore and got to know that semaphore maintains a set of permits or allowed number of locks but still i am having lots of doubts.

Is the allowed number of locks are maintained per instance of the class or whole class itself ?

I mean to say when semaphore is restricted to 2 as per my code , how come 4 threads acquired the lock.

Does this mean permits are maintained per instance of the class.If yes,
then will it not generate inconsistency in the state of the code?

On running below code , output is as follows :

```
t1 having ts1 acqired lock
t2 having ts2 acqired lock
t3 having ts1 acqired lock
t4 having ts2 acqired lock
t1 having ts1 released lock
t4 having ts2 released lock
t3 having ts1 released lock
t2 having ts2 released lock
```

The code:

```
public class SemaphoreTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Task ts1=new Task();
        Task ts2=new Task();
        Thread t1=new Thread(ts1,"t1 having ts1");
        Thread t2=new Thread(ts2,"t2 having ts2");
        Thread t3=new Thread(ts1,"t3 having ts1");
        Thread t4=new Thread(ts2,"t4 having ts2");
        t1.start();
        t3.start();
        t2.start();
        t4.start();

    }
}

class Task implements Runnable{
    Semaphore noOfLocks=new Semaphore(2);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            noOfLocks.acquire();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" acqired lock");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            noOfLocks.release();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" released lock");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You have two semaphores that allow two locks each. That's 4. I fail to see a problem here.

Comment: That's not the output I get at all. Your semaphores (2 of them) only have 1 permit. Only one thread will be able to access each one at a time.

Comment: @biziclop I need a confirmation whether number of allowed locks are maintained on each instance. Since I have mentioned 2 locks and created 2 objects so 4 threads are able to acquire lock. If two threads got the lock on same object then they may produce some inconsistent state by trying to update the value of same instance variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i have changed the code as per output. Kindly try

Comment: Please try to understand the question before down voting and demoralizing anyone

Comment: You have two semaphores with two permits each. You have two threads sharing a semaphore each. What output do you expect and why?

Comment: The number of permits is per semaphore object (as you'd expect). You created two separate tasks, which in turn created their own semaphore objects (one each), I still don't understand what the question is, I'm sorry.

Comment: If we don't understand the question, it's because it's unclear and therefore probably deserves the downvote. Don't be demoralized, just improve your question.

Comment: @biziclop Suppose there is an instance variable of hashmap in class Task and in my run() method , I am doing like this : if(!hasmap.contains(key)){hashmap.put(key,value)} T1 on ts1 checks condition & enter inside If block. Now CPU is switched from T1 to T3 which also checks condition on ts1 and gets inside If block. Now we have 2 threads inside IF block which may result in either T1 overwriting T3 value or vice-versa and that's an undesirable situation. How is this getting handled or is there any gap in my understanding.

Comment: Why do you have a variable named `noOfLocks` when its value is a reference to a `Semaphore`?  `noOfLocks` sounds like "number of locks" which sounds like it should be an `int`.  You will get a better quality of help with your problems if you strive to write code that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each instance of your `Task` class has it's own instance of a `Semaphore`.

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    Semaphore noOfLocks=new Semaphore(2);
    ...
```

And each semaphore instance has it's own permit counter.

You create two `Task` instances, thus you have 2 `Semaphore` instances with initially 2 permits each.

```
    Task ts1=new Task();
    Task ts2=new Task();
```

Executing `ts1` in multiple threads at the same time will result in threads fighting for the same semaphore. As will executing `ts2` in multiple threads. In your code those:

```
    Thread t1=new Thread(ts1,"t1 having ts1");
    Thread t3=new Thread(ts1,"t3 having ts1");
```

and

```
    Thread t2=new Thread(ts2,"t2 having ts2");
    Thread t4=new Thread(ts2,"t4 having ts2");
```

So in the end there are 2 Threads using 2 out of 2 permits times 2. Nothing needs to wait for permits since there are enough for everybody.

If you want to see something, make more threads using the existing tasks or decrease the amount of initial permits.

Comment: Suppose there is an instance variable of hashmap in class Task and in my run() method , I am doing like this : if(!hasmap.contains(key)){hashmap.put(key,value)} T1 on ts1 checks condition & enter inside If block. Now CPU is switched from T1 to T3 which also checks condition on ts1 and gets inside If block. Now we have 2 threads inside IF block which may result in either T1 overwriting T3 value or vice-versa and that's an undesirable situation. How is this getting handled or is there any gap in my understanding.If it's unhandled by semaphore, then what  is the advantage of it ?

Comment: @user2800089 It works fine if you protect the entire process of `if(!h ...lue)}` with a semaphore that has exactly 1 permit. T3 would then have to wait because the permit (and thereby access to the hashmap) is owned by T1 while it modifies it. Semaphores with more then 1 permit are not useful to protect things that can only be used by 1 thread at a time, so you usually use `synchronized` or a `ReentrantLock` instead, since those have only 1 "permit". Semaphores are used in other scenarios, e.g. you have a database connection pool and you don't want to use more than 5 connections in parallel.

Comment: thanks a lot. That was my whole question and now it got clarified.

Comment: Kindly explain me the output of the snippet present in given link [snippet](http://goo.gl/41zUc6)  when only 2 permits are declared per instances then why I am able to release 4 permits and how count of available permits is reaching to 7.

Comment: @user2800089 a Semaphore does not restrict you to the amount of initially available permits. You can freely add, and take them away as you see fit. You don't even have to give back where you take them. You can write code where one thread produces permits and another one consumes them to get rate limited execution.  The 7 in your code happens as follows: You start with 2 permits, then 2 threads take 2 and add 4 so you are at 8 (2 -1+4 -1+4). Then the third thread takes another one and you're at 7. Before that thread releases another 4 it prints the 7. There will be 11 permits at the very end.